# Replace levels of factor with levels of another factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df1` with a factor called `lepsp` and `ID` and a second data frame `df2` with a factor called `lepsp_updates` and `matchID`. I need to update all the `lepsp` info in df1 with that in  `lepsp_updates` in `df2`.

This would require overwriting/replacing some current `lepsp` levles or filling in blank entries for that column. However, currently the `lepsp_updates` has `NA` for many entries and I do not want NAs to replace current entries for `lepsp`. Here is the current data frame:

```
  df1<- data.frame(ID= seq(1,10, 1), 
               lepsp= c("A", "B", "", "C", "B", "","", "A", "B" , "C")) 
  df2<- data.frame(matchID= c("2","3", "8"), 
                   lepsp_updates= c("C", "E", "B"))
```

The output would look like:

```
 output<- data.frame(ID= seq(1,10, 1), 
               lepsp= c("A", "C", "E", "C", "B", "","", "B", "B" , "C"))
```

Notice for ID 2 B was replaced with C and ID3 E replaced the blank entry. All other original entries for df1 remained unchanged.

I have tried versions of:

```
df1$lepsp<- df2$lepsp_updated[match(df1$ID, df2$matchID)]
```

or adding a column to df1 with the updates and then merging columns.

```
df1 <- transform(df1, lepsp_updated = ifelse(is.na(lepsp_updated),lepsp, lepsp_updated))
```

But factors are either changed to numbers or data is overwritten and only data from one factor level remains.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = seq(1, 10, 1), 
                 lepsp = c("A", "B", "", "C", "B", "", "", "A", "B" , "C"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

df2 <- data.frame(matchID = c("2", "3", "8"), 
                 lepsp_updates = c("C", "E", "B"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

df2$matchID <- as.numeric(df2$matchID)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "matchID")) %>% 
  mutate(lepsp = if_else(is.na(lepsp_updates), lepsp, lepsp_updates)) %>% 
  select(ID, lepsp)
```

Which returns:

```
#    ID lepsp
# 1   1     A
# 2   2     C
# 3   3     E
# 4   4     C
# 5   5     B
# 6   6      
# 7   7      
# 8   8     B
# 9   9     B
# 10 10     C
```

Note that you have to include the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument in `data.frame` and you also need to convert the `matchID` to numeric if you want this solution to work.

Also, it's probably a good idea to convert blank characters to `NA`. You could do this by adding an additional `mutate` to the chain:

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "matchID")) %>% 
  mutate(lepsp = if_else(is.na(lepsp_updates), lepsp, lepsp_updates)) %>% 
  select(ID, lepsp) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., . == '', NA)))

#    ID lepsp
# 1   1     A
# 2   2     C
# 3   3     E
# 4   4     C
# 5   5     B
# 6   6  <NA>
# 7   7  <NA>
# 8   8     B
# 9   9     B
# 10 10     C
```

Alternatively, you can convert the blank characters to `NA` with base R:

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "matchID")) %>% 
  mutate(lepsp = if_else(is.na(lepsp_updates), lepsp, lepsp_updates)) %>% 
  select(ID, lepsp)

df[df == ""] = NA
```